# Undefined method for `before_filter'

Tags: ruby-on-rails-5.1

I am running into the following error despite the method being clearly defined in the next line.

```
undefined method `before_filter' for AuthorsController:Class
```

I am following this [tutorial](http://tutorials.jumpstartlab.com/projects/blogger.html#i5:-authentication).

Code snippet as follows:

**authors_controller.rb**

```
class AuthorsController < ApplicationController

  before_action :set_author, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  before_filter :zero_authors_or_authenticated, only: [:new, :create] 

  def zero_authors_or_authenticated
    # If either one of them is true this filter won’t do anything, allowing the requested user registration form to be rendered
    unless Author.count == 0 || current_user # checking if there are either zero registered users OR if there is a user already logged in
      redirect_to root_path # if neither are true, then redirect to root_path and return false
      return false
    end
  end

  # GET /authors
  # GET /authors.json
  def index
    @authors = Author.all
  end

  # GET /authors/1
  # GET /authors/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /authors/new
  def new
    @author = Author.new
  end

  # GET /authors/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /authors
  # POST /authors.json
  def create
    @author = Author.new(author_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @author.save
        format.html { redirect_to @author, notice: 'Author was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @author }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @author.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /authors/1
  # PATCH/PUT /authors/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @author.update(author_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @author, notice: 'Author was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @author }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @author.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /authors/1
  # DELETE /authors/1.json
  def destroy
    @author.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to authors_url, notice: 'Author was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_author
      @author = Author.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def author_params
      params.require(:author).permit(:username, :email, :password, :password_confirmation)
    end
end
```

Using Sorcery as authentication, windows 10, visual code.

Comment: Which version of Rails are you using?

Comment: Rails 5.1.2, thanks i wasn't aware before_filter is deprecated.

Comment: There;s no difference between `before_action` and `before_filter` excepting that `before_filter` is deprecated or removed.  Use `before_action` instead.

Answer (score 85, accepted):

Try using

```
before_action :zero_authors_or_authenticated, only: [:new, :create]
```

Instead of

```
before_filter :zero_authors_or_authenticated, only: [:new, :create]
```

`before_filter` has been deprecated in Rails 5.0 and removed in 5.1.

Comment: Weird that this isn't in the 5.0 migration guide?

Comment: @Meekohi Please see this http://guides.rubyonrails.org/5_0_release_notes.html#deprecations

Answer (score 7):

If you are getting this error in Rails version < 5, check whether you have inherited your controller from action controller

```
class AuthorsController < ApplicationController
end
```

Answer (score 4):

Setup for milia on rails version 5.2

**Gemfile:**

- gem 'devise'
- gem 'milia'

**Application Controller:**

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_action :authenticate_tenant! 
end
```

**devise_permitted_parameter.rb:**

```
  included do
    before_filter :configure_permitted_parameters
  end
```

Change above to

```
included do
    before_action :configure_permitted_parameters
  end
```

**Run Command:**
rails g milia:install --org_email='do-not-reply@local-test.dev'

Important Note: Say No (N) when it asks for the overwriting the
     **devise_permitted_parameter.rb** file